# AngularJS: Preventing user from accessing a certain state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sails.js

I'm building an app using sails.js backend and angular in frontend. I'm trying to prevent the user from accessing the admin control page if he's not authorized. I've run into couple of answers already, but none of them seem to fully work.

At the moment in my app.js, I have

```
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
  url: "/home",
  templateUrl: "home/homeTemplate.html",
  controller: 'homeController'
})
.state('adminPage', {
  url: "/adminPage",
  templateUrl: "adminPage/adminTemplate.html",
  controller: 'adminPageController',
  resolve: {
    validate: function($q, $sails, $location) {
      var defer = $q.defer();
      $sails.get("/user/getCurrentUser")
          .success(function(response) {
            if (response.user.accessAdminPage) {
              defer.resolve();
            }
            else {
              defer.reject("Access blocked");
              $location.path('/');
            }
            return defer.promise;
          })
    }
  }
})
```

The current code is partially working; The problem at the moment is, that when the unauthorized user first logs in and lands on the home page, and then accesses `localhost:1337/#/adminPage`, he actually reaches the page. The url in the address bar changes to `localhost:1337/#/home` but the user isn't redirected. Now the weird part is, when accessing the home page afterwards through the navbar and trying to access the admin page again, the user IS redirected to the home page as intended (although there's an annoying 'flash' while the page is reloaded).

For other people asking, this kind of handling has worked, and I'm wondering what I may have missed and generally any reasons for why my current solution isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning promise from success function, this will never work.
You should return `defered.promise` (promise object) from outside success function.

**CODE**

```
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
        url: "/home",
        templateUrl: "home/homeTemplate.html",
        controller: 'homeController'
    })
.state('adminPage', {
  url: "/adminPage",
  templateUrl: "adminPage/adminTemplate.html",
  controller: 'adminPageController',
  resolve: {
    validate: function($q, $sails, $location) {
      var defer = $q.defer();
      $sails.get("/user/getCurrentUser")
      .success(function(response) {
        if (response.user.accessAdminPage) {
          defer.resolve();
        } else {
          defer.reject("Access blocked");
          $location.path('/');
        }

      });
      return defer.promise;
    }
  }
});
```

Hopefully this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: Well that was awfully simple. Working perfectly now, thanks! :)

Comment: @Fissio  do upvote/accept answer if it does helped you, Thanks :) :p

Answer (score 0):

With the solution given by pankajparkar, the issue is that you will have to reply the logic in each state declaration. I recommend you to check the user's authorization in the `onStateChangeStart` event

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
  .run(function($rootScope, AuthService){
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
      function(event, next, nextParams, prev, prevParams) {
        AuthService.isNotAutorized()
          .then(function() {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            $state.go('defaultState');
          });
    });
  });
```